# <p: ​selectOneMenu /> <f: selectItems> do not appear

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm developing a java application using jsf and put the `<p: ​​selectOneMenu />`  component primefaces in my project,But the `<p: ​​selectOneMenu /> <f: selectItems>` component items do not appear and `<selectOneMenu />` has disappeared

UPDATE

```
 <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="tamanho">
          <p>Tamanho:</p> <p:selectOneMenu id="tamanhos" value="#{tamanho.tamanho}" styleClass="tamanho" effect="fold" editable="true">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
               <f:selectItems value="#{tamanho.tamanhos_roupas}" />

    </p:selectOneMenu>

 @ManagedBean(name="tamanho")
 @RequestScoped
 public class Tamanho {

private String tamanho;
private List<SelectItem> tamanhos_roupas; // +getter (no setter necessary)

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
 tamanhos_roupas = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    tamanhos_roupas.add(new SelectItem("PP", "PP"));
    tamanhos_roupas.add(new SelectItem("P", "P"));
    tamanhos_roupas.add(new SelectItem("M", "M"));
    tamanhos_roupas.add(new SelectItem("G", "G"));
   tamanhos_roupas.add(new SelectItem("GG", "GG"));
   }



 public String getTamanho() {
    return tamanho;
 }

 public void setTamanho(String tamanho) {
    this.tamanho = tamanho;
 }

public List<SelectItem> getTamanhos_roupas() {
    return tamanhos_roupas;
}
}
```

Look how the copier of the primefaces was, disappeared itens the `<p:selectOneMenu/>`

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsWVq.jpg)

Comment: check this wiki on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Comment: I've seen the wiki and I've now implemented my selectMenu with a list but now it shows the menu but without the intens  updated the question with the code of the wiki list and how is the page now

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the log ?

Comment: I saw the log and it has no exception

Comment: BUT I'M IMPLEMENTING THE DYNAMIC LIST, THAT THE VALUE ITEM IS EMPTY AND ITEM LABEL IS THIS, ITEM LABEL = "- select one -"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "#{tamanho.tamanhos_roupas}" is a list that has values in it already, so what you need to do is add **'var'**, **'itemValue'** and **'itemLabel'** in your selectItems tag.

The **'var'** attribute is the name of the variable of your list elements in every iteration, **'itemValue'** is what #{tamanho.tamanho} value will be after selecting an option and **'itemLabel'** is what will the user read to identify that option.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="tamanho">
    <p>Tamanho:</p> <p:selectOneMenu id="tamanhos" value="#{tamanho.tamanho}"
                        styleClass="tamanho" effect="fold" editable="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tamanho.tamanhos_roupas}" var="tamanho" 
                            itemValue="#{tamanho}" itemLabel="#{tamanho.stringNome}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

See, the way your code is written you are only giving your SelectOneMenu the information you have items to iterate, but you never tell him what is the name and value of those items.